# Limit IAM role statement access by tag - serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to give access to a `lambda` function to manage (create/destroy, etc) `route53` resources but only those that have a specific tag `key` and `value` pair. This is the relevant portion of the `serverless.yaml` file:

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x

  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action: "route53:*"
          Resource: "*"
          # Condition: ??

functions:
  lambda:
    handler: index.handler
```

Basically do [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html) but with serverless. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, I found a reference from [serverless docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml) in the IAM permissions section so the solution would be like this:

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x

  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action: "route53:*"
          Resource: "*"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              aws:ResourceTag/key: "value"

functions:
  lambda:
    handler: index.handler
```